# ListBox does not refresh when data in Database is changed

Tags: c#, winforms

When I insert new Data into my database my listbox doesn't update.
I checked if the Data is written into the Database, and it is.

This is how I bound my Databasetable to my Listbox after InitilizingComponents

```
DataSet ds = DBDataSet;
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = ds.Tables["countries"];
lb_type.DataSource = bs;
lb_type.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Unless you're inserting your new data into that datatable that the bs is bound to, and then using a DataAdapter to save it, you'll need to re download the data from the database

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using a button when adding a new data in the database, so put this code inside the click event of your button.

```
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: I insert the data from an other form I open from the form with the listbox